# HTTP through a proxy server is not allowed

Tags: apache, tomcat, centos, port80

When I try to connect to my `Tomcat` server on `http://<servername>:8080` it works fine, but from another ISP provided it gives the following error:

```
HTTP through a proxy server is not allowed.
```

Some ISP apparently don't allow http over the port 8080, as they think the client uses a proxy.

I also have a `httpd` running on port 80 for my website.

So in order to avoid the proxy error, I would like to make to following routing:

- If the user connects to `http://<servername>`, then the website is served via apache.
- If the user connects to  `http://<servername>/AppName`, then the port is rerouted to 8080, without the client (or his ISP) knowing.

Is that possible (using iptables or something else)  ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can configure Apache to do this for you using mod_proxy

In your apache conf add something like this

```
ProxyPass /appName http://localhost:8080/appName
ProxyPassReverse /appName http://localhost:8080/appName
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html

With Tomcat you can also use mod_proxy AJP

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html